# Javascript multidimensional array updating specific element

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have a string that has been converted into an 2D Array in js.

#### board = "...|.X.|...|"

It is used to represent a game board

each . represents a space

each | represents a row

each X represents a wall

#### EDIT: code below for the 2d array creation

```
var src= "...|.X.|...|";
board = src.split(/\|/g);

for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
var cells = board[i].split('');
for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
    cells[j] = parseInt(cells[j]);
}
board[i][j] = cells;
console.log(board[1][1])
//returns 'X'
```

when i access board[i][j] it returns correctly:

#### [0][0] = "."

#### [1][1] = "X"

#### [1][2] = "."

etc etc

I want to update the specific element with a string representing a piece.
However when i insert into an element like so:

#### board[0][0] = "piece4"

The array returns in firebug as so:

#### board = "piece4|.X.|...|"

When it should look like:

#### board = ".piece4.|.X.|...|"

Why are elements [0][1] and [0][2] being overwritten? Am I not understanding arrays of array index access correctly in js?

Comment: they should be starting from (0,0)

Comment: I only see one-dimensional strings in your example code. Where are those 2-dim arrays? The code as shown - assign a string to var "board" and then access it with [0][0] - simply does not work (returns undefined - naturally!).

Comment: Without code, there is no prove that the array really has the structure you believe it to have. So, please include the array/code as well.

Comment: Well how are you getting the string back from the array?

Comment: if you went `a = 1;` and later `a = 2` you wouldn't expect a to be 3, why would you expect any different in an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### PROBLEM:

I'm betting that you have a one-dimensional array with strings stored in each. So your array actually looks like:

```
array (
    [0] => '...',
    [1] => '.X.',
    [2] => '...'
)
```

When this is what you want:

```
array (
    [0] => array (
        [0] => '.',
        [1] => '.',
        [2] => '.'
    ),
    [1] => array (
        [0] => '.',
        [1] => 'X',
        [2] => '.'
    ),
    [2] => array (
        [0] => '.',
        [1] => '.',
        [2] => '.'
    )
)
```

### SOLUTION:

When constructing your 2D array, make sure you explicitly declare each entry in `board` as an array. So to construct it, your code might look something like this:

```
board = new Array();
rows = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    board[i] = new Array('.', '.', '.');
```

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is the problem. My string parsing into a 2D array loop is incorrect.

Answer (score 76):

I just had the same problem, but it had a more complex reason and I want to add it, in case someone finds this page searching for the same problem I had:

I had created and filled a 2-dimensional array like this:

```
var foo = Array(n).fill(Array(n).fill(0));
```

which creates a 2-dimensional n*n array filled with zeroes.

Now when I tried to overwrite a cell like this

```
foo[1][1] = 1;
```

I ended up with these values:

```
[[0,1,0],
 [0,1,0],
 [0,1,0]]
```

which is really surprising IMHO.

The reason for this was, that there has only been *one* row, which had internally been *referenced* three times. So when I changed the first index in "the second" row, it effectively changed all rows.

Bottom line: don't use `Array.fill` to create multi-dimensional arrays!

Comment: That sucks! `fill()` seemed like the perfect way to create a 2d zero-filled array until I ran into exactly the same problem.

Comment: Great language behavior.. I was questioning my own sanity over this problem for a solid hour until I found your answer. Thank you, Sir!

Comment: I also got into this problem when creating the multi-dimensional array but I created array using .push(). How to overcome this problem when using .push() to create multi-dimensional array.

Comment: you probably create one row and then .push() that again and again(?) You need to iterate the rows and create a new row in every iteration.

Comment: For close to an hour I also kept trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Days wasted debugging my algorithm, until realized issue was with array behaving unexpectedly :(

Comment: @Lyes answer below to create array solve this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64954317/631631

Comment: You can use 
`let foo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Array(n).fill(Array(n).fill(0))));`

Answer (score 1):

An other way to create a 2D array in javascript is to use `Array.from` function

```
  var 2Darr =  Array.from(Array(5), () => {
                 return new Array(5).fill(0)
             })
```

This will create a 5 x 5 array completely filled with 0. `Array.from` takes two parameters, the first one is an javascript iterable Object to extract the array from, the second one is an optional callback where we can specify something to apply to the array elements.

Accessing the element can be done simply like in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem. So after reading a lot... this finally suited my needs.

```
myArr = [1,1,1];
var arr = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  arr[i] = Array.from(myArr);
}

//lets edit 3 positions
arr[0][1]= -1;
arr[3][2]= 100;
arr[8][0] = 8080;


for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
console.log(i + " === " + arr[i]);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**
if you noticed only the edited index values changed... nothing else

```
0 === 1,-1,1  <---
1 === 1,1,1
2 === 1,1,1
3 === 1,1,100 <---
4 === 1,1,1
5 === 1,1,1
6 === 1,1,1
7 === 1,1,1
8 === 8080,1,1 <---
9 === 1,1,1
```

Comment: This is an absolutely simple and perfect example. Now I use this format to avoid the duplication while updating an index!

Answer (score 0):

Two remarks here:

1. Arrays start with index 0 in every dimension.
2. If you access a string as a 2D array, every element is a char rather than a string.

So if you write `board[0][0] = 'X';` then you get the right behavior (and that changes the first character of the string, not the second).

Answer (score 0):

The situation and solution given above is pretty simple. The issue of updating specific values in a list of objects (often referred to as an array, but that's a discussion for a different time) has more practical and industrial application. The problem you tend to run into is thinking that looking at a value in a specific cell, e.g. my_array[0][0] returns 'some value' will also let you change that value through an assignment e.g. my_array[0][0] = 'new value'. You will find that depending on how you defined your array, the change shows in the same row across the columns, not what you are needing. 
Look at the example code as an illustration of creating, and managing a multidimensional list of objects (array).

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript Object List/Array</title>
<script>
//Make a JavaScript array that can manage data of inventory between different locations over time.
var list_of_brands = ["BMW","Harley Davidson","Honda","Kawasaki"];
var list_of_locations = ["Dayton","Cincinnati"];

//a month of data
var DAYS_IN_A_MONTH = 30;
var calendar = [];
for(day_of_sales = 1; day_of_sales <= DAYS_IN_A_MONTH; day_of_sales++){

  //hold your locations
  var shop_location = [];//You need to create a new array for each day - that's part of the trick!

  for(location_index = 0;location_index < list_of_locations.length;location_index++){

  //set up some starting inventory
  var inventory = [];//You need to create a new array for each location - that's part of the trick!

      for(brand_index = 0; brand_index < list_of_brands.length; brand_index++){ 

        inventory[list_of_brands[brand_index]] = {"brand": list_of_brands[brand_index], "on_hand": 10,"sold": 0};

      };//end inventory loop

      shop_location[list_of_locations[location_index]] = {"city":list_of_locations[location_index],inventory};

  }//end location loop

  calendar[day_of_sales] = {"Day": day_of_sales, shop_location};

}//end calendar loop

//check your work
console.log('calendar:'); console.log(calendar);
console.log('shop_location:'); console.log(shop_location);
console.log('specific information: '); console.log(calendar[1].shop_location["Dayton"].inventory['BMW'].brand);//returns 'BMW'
console.log('change Dayton.BMW information: '); console.log(calendar[1].shop_location["Dayton"].inventory['BMW'].brand="Triumph");//change value
console.log('check work (Dayton.BMW): '); console.log(calendar[1].shop_location["Dayton"].inventory['BMW'].brand);//check work - PASS
console.log('check work (Cincinnati.BMW): '); console.log(calendar[1].shop_location["Cincinnati"].inventory["BMW"].brand);//check work other location - PASS!!

//Make some lasting and specific changes
console.log("Now make a change in the month's value over showing a sale on the 13th");
var sale_date = 13;
console.log("date of sale " + sale_date + "th");

var original_number_on_hand = calendar[sale_date].shop_location["Dayton"].inventory["BMW"].on_hand;
console.log("original_number_on_hand on that date: " + original_number_on_hand);

var number_of_units_sold = 3;
console.log("number_of_units_sold on that date: " + number_of_units_sold);

var new_inventory_level = original_number_on_hand - number_of_units_sold;
console.log("new_inventory_level: " + new_inventory_level);

for(date_index = sale_date; date_index  <= DAYS_IN_A_MONTH; date_index ++){  
  calendar[date_index].shop_location["Dayton"].inventory["BMW"].sold = number_of_units_sold;
  calendar[date_index].shop_location["Dayton"].inventory["BMW"].on_hand = new_inventory_level;
}

console.log("Show change in inventory");
  console.log(list_of_locations[0]+" has " + calendar[10].shop_location["Dayton"].inventory["BMW"].on_hand + " " + list_of_locations[1]+" has " + calendar[10].shop_location["Cincinnati"].inventory["BMW"].on_hand);
  console.log(list_of_locations[0]+" has " + calendar[11].shop_location["Dayton"].inventory["BMW"].on_hand + " " + list_of_locations[1]+" has " + calendar[11].shop_location["Cincinnati"].inventory["BMW"].on_hand);
  console.log(list_of_locations[0]+" has " + calendar[12].shop_location["Dayton"].inventory["BMW"].on_hand + " " + list_of_locations[1]+" has " + calendar[12].shop_location["Cincinnati"].inventory["BMW"].on_hand);
  console.log(list_of_locations[0]+" has " + calendar[13].shop_location["Dayton"].inventory["BMW"].on_hand + " " + list_of_locations[1]+" has " + calendar[13].shop_location["Cincinnati"].inventory["BMW"].on_hand);
  console.log(list_of_locations[0]+" has " + calendar[14].shop_location["Dayton"].inventory["BMW"].on_hand + " " + list_of_locations[1]+" has " + calendar[14].shop_location["Cincinnati"].inventory["BMW"].on_hand);
  console.log(list_of_locations[0]+" has " + calendar[15].shop_location["Dayton"].inventory["BMW"].on_hand + " " + list_of_locations[1]+" has " + calendar[15].shop_location["Cincinnati"].inventory["BMW"].on_hand);
  console.log(list_of_locations[0]+" has " + calendar[16].shop_location["Dayton"].inventory["BMW"].on_hand + " " + list_of_locations[1]+" has " + calendar[16].shop_location["Cincinnati"].inventory["BMW"].on_hand);

  //add new items to a shop's inventory
var inventory_2 =[];
for(brand_index = 0; brand_index < list_of_brands.length; brand_index++){ 

  inventory_2[list_of_brands[brand_index]] = {"brand": list_of_brands[brand_index], "on_hand": 10,"sold": 0};

};//end inventory loop
console.log("show inventory_2");console.log(inventory_2);
console.log("add inventory");inventory_2["Indian"] = {"brand": "Indian", "on_hand": 10,"sold": 0};
console.log("show updated inventory_2");console.log(inventory_2);

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>look in the JavaScript console for output</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which updates a specific element in a 2d array without mutating the original array (it returns a new 2d array):

```js
const update2dArray = (arr, rowIndex, columnIndex, newValue) => {
  const nextArr = structuredClone(arr)
  if (!arr?.[rowIndex]?.[columnIndex]) {
    return nextArr
  }
  nextArr[rowIndex][columnIndex] = newValue
  return nextArr
}
```