# JavaScript Array acts weird

Tags: javascript

I have an Array in a class, when I try to change values in JavaScript i get weird results. Here are some weird things from my console:

```
grid.grid
(10) [Array(8), Array(8), Array(8), Array(8), Array(8), Array(8), Array(8), Array(8), Array(8), Array(8)]
0: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
5: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
6: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
7: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
8: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
9: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
grid.grid[4][4] = 1;
grid.grid
(10) [Array(8), Array(8), Array(8), Array(8), Array(8), Array(8), Array(8), Array(8), Array(8), Array(8)]
0: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
1: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
2: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
3: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
4: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
5: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
6: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
7: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
8: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
9: (8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

This is how I created the Array:

```
createGrid() {
 let grid = [];
 let subgrid = [];
 for(let i=0; i<this.cols; i++) {
   subgrid.push(0);
 }
 for(let i=0; i<this.rows; i++) {
   grid.push(subgrid);
 }
 return grid;
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the grid?

Comment: @JonasWilms I edited my question a bit, made a weird discovery, also added the code of the array.

Comment: You only create one "subgrid"  so all the rows are pointing to the same array

Comment: Move `let subgrid` into the loop.

Comment: Thank you guys so much, I fixed the problem now. Never knew it still "remembers" the old Array variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979560/javascript-multidimensional-array-updating-specific-element